# Why isn't this document.getElementById() function working?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get a div ball to move left using javascript and 
`document.getElementById("ball").style.left = i + "px";`

This is the code that i'm using (below). I was thinking to use the `while(true) {}` loop, but it just crashed on me...

Does anyone know how to do/fix this??

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Current_Cashew57/t7peufxo/59/)

```
   <script>
        //while(true) {
        var ballLeft = 250;
        document.getElementById("ball").style.left = ballLeft;
        ballLeft =-2;
        //  }

    </script>
```

**EDIT**

The `<script>` tag is placed inside the `<body>`

**EDIT 2**

My issue is that the ball is not moving.

Comment: Does the HTML element with the id of ball exist

Comment: What is your actual issue? and Please post the markup

Comment: I have a div with an id of ball:

Comment: <div id="ball"></div>

Comment: CSS:#ball {
                background-color: black;
                height: 20px;
                width: 20px;
                border-radius: 20px;
                transition: left 1s;
                position: fixed;
                float: right;
            }

Comment: You probably mean `ballLeft -=2;` instead of `ballLeft =-2;`

Comment: Some CSS values (including left) need an unit, unitless values are treated as zero or ignored.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is single-threaded (with some very specific exceptions that do not apply here). That single thread executes tasks one at a time, exclusively. Executing a script is one task. Repainting the browser is another; answering a click is yet another. If you run an infinite task (like a `while (true) { ... }`), the browser will never again have time to interact with you.

Make sure any infinite loop is broken up by frequent timeouts, or - even better, for an animation job - use  [`window.requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

```js
const ball = document.getElementById('ball');
let position = 250;

function tick(ts) {
  ball.style.left = `${position}px`;
  position -= 2;
  if (position > 0) window.requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(tick);
```

```css
#ball {
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="ball">
  
</div>
```

Comment: I will try this answer!!

Comment: I added a simple example.

Comment: Where do you see jQuery?